# collect_list in scala dataframe which will collect rows in an interval of fixed column numbers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to collect all rows for a particular partition into one single row in dataframe.
I have to dump this dataframe into cosmosDB which can hold only 2MB of data for each document.
But when I collect the above dataframe into a single row, it exceeds 2MB and throwing error while writing into CosmosDB.

I thought of collecting the rows into one for a fixed interval of 500 rows.
For a partition first 500 rows should be collected into one row , next 500 into another and so on..

The input data is as shown below.

```
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|ID    |TIME      |SGNL                                   |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}|
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

I tried the as below but some of the rows exceeds size of 2MB which cannot be write into cosmosDB:

```
val newDF = df.groupBy($"ID", $"TIME").agg(collect_list($"SGNL").as("SGNL"))
```

The output is as below with n number of rows combined into one row of column SGNL

```
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID    |TIME      |SGNL                                                                                                                                                           |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},.......................................|
|00002 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"},.......................................| 
|00003 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"},.......................................| 
|00004 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"},.......................................|                                        |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It should be in the below format:

```
+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|ID    |TIME      |SGNL                                        |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|00001 |1574360355|{1st ROW},{2nd ROW},......{500th ROW}       |
|00001 |1574360355|{501st ROW},{502nd ROW},......{1000th ROW}  |
|00001 |1574360355|{1001st ROW},{1002nd ROW},......{1500th ROW}|
|00001 |1574360355|{1501st ROW},{1502nd ROW},......{2000th ROW}|
|..............................................................|
|..............................................................|

|00002 |1574360355|{1st ROW},{2nd ROW},......{500th ROW}       |
|00002 |1574360355|{501st ROW},{502nd ROW},......{1000th ROW}  |
|00002 |1574360355|{1001st ROW},{1002nd ROW},......{1500th ROW}|
|00002 |1574360355|{1501st ROW},{1502nd ROW},......{2000th ROW}|
|..............................................................|
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried to achieve this but i am only able to collect first n number of rows and rest of the rows will be ignored.
It should not collect only 1st 500 rows but collect all the rows at an interval of 500.
Any idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build an index using `monitonicallyIncreasingId`, divide it by 500 and group by that index. It will put the first 500 rows together, the next 500 together, and so on and so forth.

```scala
df.withColumn("fancy_id", floor(monotonicallyIncreasingId / 500))
  .groupBy("fancy_id")
  .agg(collect_list($"SGNL").as("SGNL"))
  .drop("fancy_id") // if you want to get rid of the artificial id.
```

If you do not want to mix your `ID` columns, you can use `groupBy("ID", "fancy_id")`.

Yet, the first group of each ID will not necessarily have a size of 500. For instance, you will end up with something like: `(id1, 500 elements), (id1, 320 elements), (id2, 180 elements), (id2, 500 elements), (id2, 500 element), (id2, 50elements), (id3, 450 elements)...`

If what you prefer is having something like `(id1, 500 elements), (id1, 320 elements), (id2, 500 elements), (id2, 500 elements), (id2, 500 element), (id2, 10 elements), (id3, 500 elements), (id3, 5 elements)...` where the first group always have 500 element, you can use a window:

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy('ID).orderBy('fancy_id)
df.withColumn("fancy_id", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
  .withColumn("rank", rank() over w)
  .groupBy($"ID", floor($"rank" / 500))
  .agg(collect_list($"SGNL").as("SGNL"))
```

Comment: Does this put 500 rows together based on any partition id or it will just put first 500 then 500 and so on...?

Comment: If you just use `.groupBy("fancy_id")`, the groups will be based on the current order of the data. Different consecutive IDs could end up together. If you use `.groupBy("ID", "fancy_id")`, different IDs won't be able to be grouped together. Yet, the size of the groups will be capped to 500 but the first group will not necessarily have a size of 500. If you need the first group to have a size of 500, you can use a Window. If that's what you need, I can update my answer.

Comment: I am currently facing problem with above implementation. I have the interval set to 5000. For 5001 records they are getting grouped as 4999 and 2. For 10001 records they are getting grouped as 4999,5000 and 2. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: You could use `monotonicallyIncreasingId mod 5000` instead of a division for instance.  It would share the records evenly between 5000 partitions. The goal of using a division was to give a hard limit to the maximum size of a partition (without limiting their number).

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I just changed .groupBy($"ID", floor($"rank" / 500)) to groupBy($"ID", floor(($"rank" -1) / 500)) so that 0-499 falls in first 500. 500 to 999 falls in next 500. Earlier it use to take 1-499 in first 500 as 500/500 would give 1 it was not considering in first bucket.